# Laravel - Model is saved with empty attribute value (NULL) to database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to save my model to the database. The model is saved into the database, but the values for the attributes are not set and stay empty.

[image]

It is a small model with only a few properties:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unit extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    protected $table = 'units';

    // Allowed fields from forms
    // protected $guarded = ['ic'];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = NULL;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $description = NULL;
}
```

**Controllers store function:**

```
/**
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:80|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',    //regex: only allows letters, hyphens and spaces explicitly',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $unit = new Unit();

    $unit->description = $request->description;
    $unit->name = $request->name;

    echo $unit->description . PHP_EOL;  //Outputs "example description"
    echo $unit->name . PHP_EOL;   //Outputs: "example name"

    $unit->save();
    ...
```

I am confused, it should work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The object `$unit` after `save()`:

```
Unit {#190 ▼
  +fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "description"
  ]
  #table: "units"
  +name: "example name"
  +description: "example description"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-01 10:18:59"
    "created_at" => "2017-03-01 10:18:59"
    "id" => 27
  ]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-01 10:18:59"
    "created_at" => "2017-03-01 10:18:59"
    "id" => 27
  ]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of $unit->save(), and what is logged in /storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: Why do you define $name and $description as data members of your class? Problem is there.

Comment: @veelen, the return value is `true`. And the log is empty, I emptied it a few minutes ago because it contained about 22000 lines. Nothing is logged right now.

Comment: Did you tried commenting `$name` and `$description` from `Model`?

Comment: What is the field type of `name` and `description` in your migration?

Comment: @veelen, the type is `string`, but i stopped using migrations a while ago, i only use phpmyadmin at the moment, the type there is `varchar(191)` for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this:

```
   /**
 * @var string
 */
public $name = NULL;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $description = NULL;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is causing the bug? I'm currious ^^

Comment: Yeah, what this means is you are setting the values of these attributes directly from the model. So if you save, it is getting these values (NULL) instead of what you are sending. It also affects data retrieval too. If you have saved data in your database and then add these lines back, when you want to retrieve, these values would be null.

Comment: Took me hours to find this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have to remove both attributes from your model class. This is because when these attributes are defined there won't be the magic `__set()` run and thus the `$obj->attributes[]` won't be populated with values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment the `$guarded` attribute and guard the `id`.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

I do assume that it has something to do with the following attribute:

```
#guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
]
```

Which probably means everything is guarded.

**Update**

How the guarded Attribute should look like.

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Comment: There is no `$guarded` attribute in my model.
However, I added `protected $primaryKey = 'id';` and tried it again, but it does not work.

Comment: Then you should add it ... It is available in your model, because it extends the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model which uses the Concerns\GuardsAttributes Trait.

Comment: do you use the artisan command `artisan make:model` to create a new model?

Comment: He already has the $fillable to whitelist the attributes he wants saved.

Comment: No i did not used `artisan make:model`. I think we only need `guarded` if we use middleware?